# Buttons are unresponsive after changing phone's datetime

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have created a new Ionic 3 project using `ionic start MyIonicProject tutorial`.

After running `ionic cordova run android` on my device and the app is running, I open my Android phone settings and go to `Date and time`, uncheck `Automatic date and time` and set my date backwards by 1.

When I go back to the app, all the buttons are not responsive anymore. No code was added to the template.

I am running on **`Ionic 3.7.1`**

Does anybody face this issue as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below `CLI`:

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --device
```

Comment: Will try this command later on. From what I understand, `--prod` means to build the app for production. Is there a reason why you have suggested this instead of the debug command?